# How to lock the variable type in Julia?

Tags: julia

I want to lock the type of a variable in Julia, how to do? For example, I define an array called weight,

```
weight = Array{Float64,1}([1,2,3])
```

Now I want to lock the type of weight as Array{Float64,1}, is it possible?

I mean if do not lock the type of weight, then if I mistakenly or casually do

```
weight = 1
```

Then weight will become an Int64 variable, so it is not longer a 1D array. This is obviously not what I want.

I just want to make sure that once I defined weight as 1D Float64 array, then if I change the type of weight, I want Julia gives me an error saying that the type of weight has been changed which is not allowed. Is it possible? Thanks!

This is useful because by doing this, it may preventing me from forgetting weight is an 1D array, and therefore preventing bugs.

Comment: Instead of `Array{Float64,1}([1,2,3])` you can just write `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]`. Julia figures out the type of your array based on its elements. The way you wrote it first creates a vector of ints, and then converts it to a vector of floats, which is wasteful.

Comment: @DNF You are right man! Yes, yes, yes I can write 1.0 2.0 3.0. Thing is that once I write this array down, I want to make sure weight is always a float array. It might be possible that in the code I may forgot weight is a float array and accidently do things like weight = 1.0, and it will make weight become just a variable instead of an array. I want to make sure that the type of weight never change. In fortran we can define the type first. But in Julia since things are dynamic, I wanted to do some type protection to prevent casual mistakes which changes the type of a variable or an array.

Comment: Sure, but these are orthogonal concerns. You can do `const weight = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `global` variables use `const`:

```
julia> const weight = Array{Float64,1}([1,2,3])
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
 2.0
 3.0

julia> weight[1]=11
11

julia> weight=99
ERROR: invalid redefinition of constant weight
```

Note that redefining the reference will throw a warning:

```
julia> const u = 5
5

julia> u=11
WARNING: redefinition of constant u. This may fail, cause incorrect answers, or produce other errors
```

You can circumvent it by using the `Ref` type:

```
julia> const z = Ref{Int}(5)
Base.RefValue{Int64}(5)

julia> z[] = 11
11

julia> z[] = "hello"
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type Int64
```

In functions use `local` with type declaration:

```
julia> function f()
           local a::Int
           a="hello"
       end;

julia> f()
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type Int64
```

Comment: thank you very much. Quick question, so I found that by doing const weight = Array{Float64,1}([1,2,3]), then I can reset its value like weight[1]=11 without warning. However, why if I do const on a variable such as, const a = 1.0, then it will give me an warning if I further do i = 1.5? The warning says, "WARNING: redefinition of constant a. This may fail, cause incorrect answers, or produce other errors."  But for array, there is no such warning?

Answer (score 2):

You'd normally write:

```
weight::Vector{Float64} = Array{Float64,1}([1,2,3])
```

...but this doesn't seem to be possible in global scope:

```
julia> weight::Vector{Float64} = Array{Float64,1}([1,2,3])
ERROR: syntax: type declarations on global variables are not yet supported
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[8]:1
```

However, you can do it in local scope or in a `struct`:

```
julia> function fun()
        weight::Vector{Float64} = Array{Float64,1}([1,2,3])
        weight = 1
       end
fun (generic function with 1 method)

julia> fun()
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type Vector{Float64}
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{T}, ::AbstractArray) where T<:Array at array.jl:532
  convert(::Type{T}, ::LinearAlgebra.Factorization) where T<:AbstractArray at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/LinearAlgebra/src/factorization.jl:58
  convert(::Type{T}, ::T) where T<:AbstractArray at abstractarray.jl:14
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] fun()
   @ Main ./REPL[10]:3
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[11]:1
```

---

You could use `const`, but then redefinition with a value of the same type will cause a warning:

```
julia> const weight = Array{Float64,1}([1,2,3]);

julia> weight = [2.]
WARNING: redefinition of constant weight. This may fail, cause incorrect answers, or produce other errors.
1-element Vector{Float64}:
 2.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks like const is way to do. Uhm, so, on the other hand, is there way to make the type stable without a warning?